# Outlook 2007 does not have a ribbon

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, ribbon

I have outlook 2007 installed (12.0.6514.5000) on my work computer.

I just installed [Bowie](http://bowie.codeplex.com/) to allow integration with outlook and TFS.

Most of the features for that plugin are based on the ribbon.  But I don't have the ribbon.  I have the old menu and toolbar structure.

How do I switch to the ribbon view?

Here is a screen shot of my outlook:

[image: Ribbon Missing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook 2007 does not have Ribbon in this view

Open a message, calendar entry or contact and you will see its Ribbon

Comment: Here is a supporting link (Info toward the middle): http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA100898951033.aspx